# Множественное добавление изображений

Tags: android, изображения

Есть форма на которую нужно добавить несколько изображений чтобы потом сохранить их во внешней базе данных?

[image: Скриншот]

Как правильно реализовать выбор несколько изображений (может чтобы окно изображение было как страницы и эти страницы можно было перелистывать)?

Comment: нашел как вариант imageSwitcher

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно запустить `Intent` примерно такого сорта:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GETN_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

И обработать в `onActivityResult` примерно так:

```
ArrayList<String> fileUris=new ArrayList<>(); //массив для хранения URI возвращенных файлов
if(intent.getData()==null) { //detecting multiple selection
    ClipData clipdata = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
         clipdata = intent.getClipData();
         for (int i=0; clipdata!=null && i < clipdata.getItemCount(); i++)
             fileUris.add(clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri().toString());
     }
     else
        fileUris.add(intent.getData().toString());
}
else { //single selection
    fileUris.add(intent.getData().toString());
}
```

`Intent` запустит встроенный в девайс селектор файлов (если есть, конечно). Если его нет, то можно использовать проект [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Comment: та нет, на мой взгляд это не удобно, удобнее нажать на превюшку изображения, как на скриншоте, сделать снимок и что бы снимок попал в превюшку, а далее пролистал на еще одну пустую превюшку и аналогично сделал снимок для нововй превюшки.

Я что то такое хотел бы реализовать...